# vertical-align:middle property with no defined height

Tags: html, css

I have the following code on my site.

HTML

```
<div class="brand-wrap">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>

        <div class="brand-text">
            <p>This is a bunch of content that may take up more than one line of text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: url('img/logo_orig.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.brand-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.brand-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I am trying to vertically align navbar-brand and brand-text, but I can only get them to be next to each other. The vertical-align: middle doesn't seem to work. (* the content may take up more than one line depending on screen width)

How can I align the content vertically?

Comment: You don't need `vertical-align: middle;` inside the _.brand-text_ class and why it doesn't look centered is because your _.navbar-brand_ class has `margin-top: 10px;` which is pushing your content around. Try using `padding-top: 10px;` in _.brand-wrap_ or _.navbar-brand._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see problem - just tried your code in here, and it seems to work as it should, or so I understand at least. Maybe be more specific about what are you trying to achieve?

Maybe you simply don't quite understand what vertical-align is supposed to do?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QboXov

```
<div class="brand-wrap">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>

        <div class="brand-text">
            <p>This is a bunch of content that may take up more than one line of text<br/>This is a bunch of content that may take up more than one line of text<br/>This is a bunch of content that may take up more than one line of text<br/>This is a bunch of content that may take up more than one line of text<br/>This is a bunch of content that may take up more than one line of text</p>
        </div>
</div>

.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: url('img/logo_orig.png') #ccc no-repeat center center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.brand-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.brand-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: that's my issue is that I can't get it to work for me, it was an answer I received. Your code pen works the way I want

Comment: my mistake I overlooked an issue, your codepen helped me realize it, thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Just a little suggestion here - try to avoid using fonts smaller than 14px in your page. Or, even better, switch to using em units instead of px.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` aligns one *block* to another...not the content of the block itself.

The difference in the positioning is the margin-top you have on your `navbar-brand`.

If you remove that you can see that everything lines up.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: orange;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.brand-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.brand-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand-wrap">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>

  <div class="brand-text">
    <p>This is a bunch of content that may take up more than one line of text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```